# How can I sync/store my PC save games to a cloud?

Tags: pc

I want to store my saves in a cloud network so I can access them anywhere. I would like to have a specific folder on my HDD, for example `D:\GameSaves`, to be automatically sync in the background.

I'm looking for a cloud service, preferably a free one which:

- Does not delete data, regardless how long inactive it is!
- Allows the use of external sync/upload/download tools

And if there's a different, it should ask me to download from `D:\GameSaves` and overwrite the old file in the cloud.

I also must be able to use 3rd party tools, and would like to get some suggestions WHICH tools I should use. (Preferably, but not mandatory, no .exe installer, .zip packed, ready to go!).

Comment: Some games have this built-in to them.  Half-Life 2 being the major example here, although that didn't start until the Mac version hit back in May or so.

Answer (score 7):

There are synchronization services which can make specific folder(s) identical across multiple machines - that sounds like it could satisfy all your needs except for the 3rd party tools, which I'm not entirely sure what you want for - and it seems you're not so sure either, as you're asking for recommendations.

For example, you could set it up so that

`C:\whatever\my fav game\save data` on computer A is always identical in content to

`D:\something\save data` on computer B.

A service I can recommend in that regard is [Syncplicity](http://www.syncplicity.com/) - a few GB free and it allows you to synchronize whatever folders you want, unlike services such as [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) which dictate which folder to use. I mean dropbox might be great for other uses, but if you want to just synchronize the folder the game already uses for saves, it's not as convenient.

Comment: since dropbox follows links to folders, that is also ok for me. Plus, I have one central place where everything synchronized is gathered

Comment: I'd also mention [Microsoft Sykdrive](http://skydrive.live.com/), especially since it's supposed to be shipped with the upcoming Windows 8.1, removing the need to install 3rd parties. Only downside as of now, is that you can't select paths to sync; only files/directories within the Skydrive folder.

Answer (score 4):

I use [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and added a link to each savegame folder in the dropbox folder. That way the software automatically synchronizes all my savegames everytime they change. I don't know about external sync/upload/download tools compatibility though.

Comment: [This](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTc0MDQ0MTk) is my **referral link**. I don't post it directly in the answer since it's irrelevant, but in case you use it you'll start with 250MB additional storage. I'll delete this comment if considered spam.

Comment: I JUST made a DropBox account 10 minutes ago :(